# Viewport scaling is not working on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am still quite new to making websites and this website I am currently working on is in early sstage of development, but I would like to make it responsive for mobile devices. I added this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` but it doesnt seem to be working, the only thing that is working is `user-scalabel=no`. I tried different variations of the scale and bunch of different arguments but the result is still the same. There is probably issue with the css. Any ideas? Thank you.

```js
function anim() {


            $(".slider").delay(1000).animate({
                width: 'show',

            }, 1000);

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause:"false"

    })
})
```

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: moccasin;
}


.secondpic {
    margin-top: 10%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    margin-top: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#text {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 5vw;
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #634731;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slider {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -60px;
    top: 0;
}

.container {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar {
    top: -100px;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    padding-top: 100px !important;
    float: right;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

.buttons {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-right: -1px;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.text-white {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.bg-secondary {
    background-color: rgba(225, 159, 113, 1) !important;

}

.buttons a:hover {
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Prosatin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script defer src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="website.js"></script>


</head>

<header>
    <div class="">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light slider">

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav buttons">
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white buttons " href="#">FOTOGALERIE</a>
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white buttons" href="#">AKCE</a>
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white buttons " href="#">O NAS</a>
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white buttons " href="#">ZPEVNIK</a>
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white buttons" href="#">KONTAKTY</a>
                    <a type="button" class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary  buttons logo"
                       href="https://www.facebook.com/letnistanovytaborProsatin/"><img src="facebook.png"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>


<body onload="anim()">


<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/sjngKLM/tabor.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/JHYhT9Z/DSC-7364.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/yS42F7s/im2.png" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="arrow" src="https://i.ibb.co/VM1v7kD/Image-5.png">
    <p class="" id="text">NEJNOVEJSI FOTOGRAFIE</p>
    <img class="secondpic" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjpppGn/Image-4.png">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0sL1fmw/3/)

[Incorrect layout on a phone](https://i.ibb.co/WyJDNcm/Screenshot-2.jpg)

I cant get the snippet and JSfiddle working properly, but it should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `Media Query` like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    // css
  }
}
```

Comment: I am awere of `Media Query` but I was hoping for this kind of [result](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) where it scales nicey with screen and lets me scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you have a markup issue. You've a `<header>` inside the `<html>` and that's wrong. The `<html>` tag only has 2 children: `<head>` and `<body>`. So, the `<header>` should be inside the `<body>` and maybe that's the problem because your meta tags are fine.
You could read more about the anatomy of an HTML document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics) (scroll a little)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, however, it is still showing the whole [website](https://i.ibb.co/WyJDNcm/Screenshot-2.jpg)

Comment: Press the 3 dots at the top-right corner of your phone and select Desktop site. See what happens